# not editable first comment after 2nd comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

if i done one comment and i write 2nd comment in any question it not allow me to edit first one comment there i have just only one option to delete it.

2nd comment is editable but first not allow me to edit .

here, both comment are commented by me.

even if after some time we cant make changes in comments like any question and answer.

is it functionality
OR
may be drawback

Comment: Testing ....... EDIT: this seems to work; this doesn't seem to be a bug. The little pen? mark at the end of this comment indicates it's been edited, as my other comment is below this one then I am able to edit earlier comments.

Comment: This is the second comment.

Comment: now try to edit first one

Comment: @Ben you should use the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) for testing purposes :C

Comment: @ajax333221, it wouldn't have demonstrated as easily as doing it on the question did.

Comment: @jubinPatel, please be aware that using `backticks` for `random formatting` of `words` makes your posts very `hard` to `read`.  Please refrain from such abuse of formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can'd edit comments after five minutes (diamond moderators are exempt from that rule). Comments have no revision history, which makes unlimited edits problematic.

Comment: +1 by me here just because i have not rights